# How to Disable JS Alert of GeckoFX 33.0 Web Browser in vs2012

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, geckofx

I have been working on a vb Project for 2 weeks. But can't disable js alert. I'm using GeckoFX 33.0 ([this](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-33.0/downloads)) . There are Many discussion But none of them is alive for me. I tried a lot. Can anyone help me to solve this Problem please ?

Comment: could you post some code example and some workarounds you did?

Comment: ok Something like this ? <script>alert('hello'); </script> If I load this in a HTML file it would give me a alert. How can I stop this ?

Comment: refer this link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931050/disable-javascript-alerts-geckofx-c-sharp/29932722#29932722)

Comment: This does not work anymore in geckofx-core 33.0

Comment: check the upgraded version 45....
i am not sure weather it helps, since i have not used it.
the link is [here](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/overview)

you need to install it as a nuget

Comment: Yes I got that. But v45 is for C#. I'm using vb :(

Comment: is it mandatory that you use version 33?
probably version 29 has a fix right?

Comment: Yes I think So. 33 is not mandatory.

Comment: you have the fix already :)

Comment: Can you just overwrite the script with your own? `window.alert = function() {};`... It won't do anything as it's just empty...

Comment: I did this But it did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28977359/361714

Answer (score 0):

please check out this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43878928/2892378

It basically means you have to implement the the nsIPromptServcice2 and nsIPrompt interfaces, but do not provide any code inside the methods defined.