# GeckoWebBrowser access an incorrect URL,Always pop up message box

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

www.addssds333fdsd.com.cn could not be found. Please check the name and try again.

```
 GeckoWebBrowser _webA = new GeckoWebBrowser();
 _webA.Navigate("www.addssds333fdsd.com.cn");
```

When I Access An incorrect URL,Application will pop up message box.

How to catch the Exception or drop the message box.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the nsIPromptServcice2 and nsIPrompt interfaces

There you will get a list of methods (e.g. `Alert();`) where you simply don't provide an implementation.
That will 'catch' the exception.

Create a following class (you will need to provide implementation for a bunch of methods, such as Alert, Confirm, Prompt etc

```
public class FilteredPromptService : nsIPromptService2, nsIPrompt
{

    public void Alert(string dialogTitle, string text)
    {
         //do your stuff here
    } 
    //... other methods to follow
}
```

Then, somewhere at the startup of the browser app (maybe in `Application_Startup()` in case of WPF), assign the prompt service:

```
PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = () => new FilteredPromptService();
```

Also, please notice that the above PromptService is static, so this will be applied to all instances of GeckoBrowser in your application.

Comment: I think that except implementing these interfaces, I will have to set their references to gecko somehow. How to do that?

Comment: @VladMatvienko - I'll update the answer with more details