# Disable JavaScript Alerts Gecko45 C#

Tags: javascript, c#, gecko, geckofx, alerts

I want to disable all js alert.This code not working gecko 45

```
geckoWebBrowser1.JavascriptError += (sender, error) => {
    GeckoWebBrowser browser = geckoWebBrowser1;
    string text = "window.alert = function(){};";
    using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(browser.Window.JSContext)) {
        string result;
        //toolStripLabel1.Text = "was is loaded?";

        context.EvaluateScript(text, (nsISupports)browser.Window.DomWindow, out result);
    }
};
```

Comment: Uhhh... Is this even Javascript? I don't think so. You could try overriding `alert` with something like `alert = function(){ }`

Comment: @JeremyThille unless OP edited their question, that is what they are trying....

Comment: That seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737542/geckowebbrowser-access-an-incorrect-url-always-pop-up-message-box/43878928#43878928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable all alerts, then you need to implement your own nsIPromptService2 where you will override the methods called when an alert happens.

```
public class FilteredPromptService : nsIPromptService2, nsIPrompt
{
        public void Alert(string dialogTitle, string text)
        {
           //do nothing, 
        }
        //and so on for other alerts/prompts
 }
```

Bear in mind you also need to register in by calling after you initialize the engine:

`PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = () => new FilteredPromptService();`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete class i had to add. It is the only working solution i have found for GeckoFX 45.

```
Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox64");
PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = () => new FilteredPromptService();
```

---

```
public class FilteredPromptService : nsIPromptService2, nsIPrompt
{   
    void nsIPromptService2.Alert(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText)
    {

    }

    void nsIPromptService2.AlertCheck(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {

    }

    bool nsIPromptService2.Confirm(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPromptService2.ConfirmCheck(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int nsIPromptService2.ConfirmEx(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, uint aButtonFlags, string aButton0Title, string aButton1Title, string aButton2Title, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPromptService2.Prompt(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, ref string aValue, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPromptService2.PromptUsernameAndPassword(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, ref string aUsername, ref string aPassword, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();   
    }

    bool nsIPromptService2.PromptPassword(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, ref string aPassword, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPromptService2.Select(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, uint aCount, IntPtr[] aSelectList, ref int aOutSelection)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPromptService2.PromptAuth(nsIDOMWindow aParent, nsIChannel aChannel, uint level, nsIAuthInformation authInfo, string checkboxLabel, ref bool checkValue)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    nsICancelable nsIPromptService2.AsyncPromptAuth(nsIDOMWindow aParent, nsIChannel aChannel, nsIAuthPromptCallback aCallback, nsISupports aContext, uint level, nsIAuthInformation authInfo, string checkboxLabel, ref bool checkValue)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void nsIPromptService.Alert(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText)
    {

    }

    void nsIPromptService.AlertCheck(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {

    }

    bool nsIPromptService.Confirm(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPromptService.ConfirmCheck(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int nsIPromptService.ConfirmEx(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, uint aButtonFlags, string aButton0Title, string aButton1Title, string aButton2Title, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPromptService.Prompt(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, ref string aValue, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPromptService.PromptUsernameAndPassword(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, ref string aUsername, ref string aPassword, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPromptService.PromptPassword(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, ref string aPassword, string aCheckMsg, ref bool aCheckState)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPromptService.Select(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText, uint aCount, IntPtr[] aSelectList, ref int aOutSelection)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void nsIPrompt.Alert(string dialogTitle, string text)
    {

    }

    void nsIPrompt.AlertCheck(string dialogTitle, string text, string checkMsg, ref bool checkValue)
    {

    }

    bool nsIPrompt.Confirm(string dialogTitle, string text)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPrompt.ConfirmCheck(string dialogTitle, string text, string checkMsg, ref bool checkValue)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int nsIPrompt.ConfirmEx(string dialogTitle, string text, uint buttonFlags, string button0Title, string button1Title, string button2Title, string checkMsg, ref bool checkValue)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPrompt.Prompt(string dialogTitle, string text, ref string value, string checkMsg, ref bool checkValue)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPrompt.PromptPassword(string dialogTitle, string text, ref string password, string checkMsg, ref bool checkValue)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPrompt.PromptUsernameAndPassword(string dialogTitle, string text, ref string username, ref string password, string checkMsg, ref bool checkValue)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool nsIPrompt.Select(string dialogTitle, string text, uint count, IntPtr[] selectList, ref int outSelection)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```